# Semantic UI CSS right padding

Tags: html, css, semantic-ui

I have this code for making a cards stackable box. The problem is that this box is showing me a right paddding in the fragment, can anyone help me?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./semantic/semantic.css"/>
    <title>Agora</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="ui teal inverted menu" style="border-radius: 0px;">
    <div class="item">
        <div class="huge ui buttons">
        <div class="ui button">One</div>
        <div class="ui button">Two</div>
        <div class="ui button">Three</div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <div class="ui button">Log-in</div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="ui column centered grid">
    <div class="fourteen wide column">
        <div class="ui center aligned segment">


            <div class="ui stackable four column centered grid" >
                <div class="column">
                    <div class="ui card">
                        <div class="image">
                            <img src="http://semantic-ui.com/images/avatar/large/elliot.jpg">
                        </div>
                        <div class="content">
                            <a class="header">Stevie Feliciano</a>
                            <div class="meta">
                                <span class="date">Joined in 2014</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="description">
                                Stevie Feliciano is a library scientist living in New York City. She likes to spend her time reading, running, and writing.
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="extra content">
                            <a>
                                <i class="user icon"></i>
                                22 Friends
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <div class="ui card">
                        <div class="image">
                            <img src="http://semantic-ui.com/images/avatar/large/elliot.jpg">
                        </div>
                        <div class="content">
                            <a class="header">Stevie Feliciano</a>
                            <div class="meta">
                                <span class="date">Joined in 2014</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="description">
                                Stevie Feliciano is a library scientist living in New York City. She likes to spend her time reading, running, and writing.
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="extra content">
                            <a>
                                <i class="user icon"></i>
                                22 Friends
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <div class="ui card">
                        <div class="image">
                            <img src="http://semantic-ui.com/images/avatar/large/elliot.jpg">
                        </div>
                        <div class="content">
                            <a class="header">Stevie Feliciano</a>
                            <div class="meta">
                                <span class="date">Joined in 2014</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="description">
                                Stevie Feliciano is a library scientist living in New York City. She likes to spend her time reading, running, and writing.
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="extra content">
                            <a>
                                <i class="user icon"></i>
                                22 Friends
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <div class="ui card">
                        <div class="image">
                            <img src="http://semantic-ui.com/images/avatar/large/elliot.jpg">
                        </div>
                        <div class="content">
                            <a class="header">Stevie Feliciano</a>
                            <div class="meta">
                                <span class="date">Joined in 2014</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="description">
                                Stevie Feliciano is a library scientist living in New York City. She likes to spend her time reading, running, and writing.
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="extra content">
                            <a>
                                <i class="user icon"></i>
                                22 Friends
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>


        </div>
    </div>
</div>




</body>
</html>
```

This is the problem image:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/90qev.png

I need to remove the padding that's in the right side.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the working example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/semantic-ui@2.4.2/dist/semantic.min.css">
    <title>Agora</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    .ui.card {
margin: auto;
}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="ui teal inverted menu" style="border-radius: 0px;">
    <div class="item">
        <div class="huge ui buttons">
        <div class="ui button">One</div>
        <div class="ui button">Two</div>
        <div class="ui button">Three</div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <div class="ui button">Log-in</div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="ui column centered grid">
    <div class="fourteen wide column">
        <div class="ui center aligned segment">


            <div class="ui stackable four column centered grid" >
                <div class="column">
                    <div class="ui card">
                        <div class="image">
                            <img src="http://semantic-ui.com/images/avatar/large/elliot.jpg">
                        </div>
                        <div class="content">
                            <a class="header">Stevie Feliciano</a>
                            <div class="meta">
                                <span class="date">Joined in 2014</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="description">
                                Stevie Feliciano is a library scientist living in New York City. She likes to spend her time reading, running, and writing.
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="extra content">
                            <a>
                                <i class="user icon"></i>
                                22 Friends
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <div class="ui card">
                        <div class="image">
                            <img src="http://semantic-ui.com/images/avatar/large/elliot.jpg">
                        </div>
                        <div class="content">
                            <a class="header">Stevie Feliciano</a>
                            <div class="meta">
                                <span class="date">Joined in 2014</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="description">
                                Stevie Feliciano is a library scientist living in New York City. She likes to spend her time reading, running, and writing.
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="extra content">
                            <a>
                                <i class="user icon"></i>
                                22 Friends
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <div class="ui card">
                        <div class="image">
                            <img src="http://semantic-ui.com/images/avatar/large/elliot.jpg">
                        </div>
                        <div class="content">
                            <a class="header">Stevie Feliciano</a>
                            <div class="meta">
                                <span class="date">Joined in 2014</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="description">
                                Stevie Feliciano is a library scientist living in New York City. She likes to spend her time reading, running, and writing.
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="extra content">
                            <a>
                                <i class="user icon"></i>
                                22 Friends
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <div class="ui card">
                        <div class="image">
                            <img src="http://semantic-ui.com/images/avatar/large/elliot.jpg">
                        </div>
                        <div class="content">
                            <a class="header">Stevie Feliciano</a>
                            <div class="meta">
                                <span class="date">Joined in 2014</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="description">
                                Stevie Feliciano is a library scientist living in New York City. She likes to spend her time reading, running, and writing.
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="extra content">
                            <a>
                                <i class="user icon"></i>
                                22 Friends
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>


        </div>
    </div>
</div>




</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be a problem that each of these cards do not fill the width of their column so they are aligned to the left.

You could use the class ".cards" which is mentioned [here](http://semantic-ui.com/views/card.html#cards) (it uses flexbox to fit the cards perfectly).

The code found in documentation:

```
<div class="ui cards">

  <div class="card">
    <a class="image">
      <img src="/images/avatar/large/elliot.jpg">
    </a>
    <div class="content">
      <a class="header">Elliot Fu</a>
      <div class="meta">
        <a>Friends</a>
      </div>
      <div class="description">
        Elliot Fu is a film-maker from New York.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="card">
    <a class="image">
      <img src="/images/avatar/large/helen.jpg">
    </a>
    <div class="content">
      <a class="header">Helen Troy</a>
      <div class="meta">
        <a>Friends</a>
      </div>
      <div class="description">
        Helen Troy is an archivist living in New York, who enjoys cooking, fine art, and gardening.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: But i want the cards to be centered... How i do that?

Comment: Sorry, I did not get it from the description. Well, if you want the cards centered inside of the columns, you could set text-align: center to the column (and maybe set the padding right to 0). If the .card has fixed width you should use margin: 0 auto.